# Browser Context Menu not get disappeared on adding a Custom Menu on Google Maps (in Windows - Chrome & Firefox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, contextmenu

I'm using Google Maps API in my react app. I've added a custom context menu on the maps on the right click button handler. It works absolutely fine on all browsers on Mac. Works fine on IE and Edge on Windows except for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox (on Windows OS) where apart from displaying the custom menu, the actual browser context menu also appears.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnxLum5j/) which contains a sample code which behaves similarly to how my code works.

Please check the above fiddle on Windows in different browsers and on right clicking the maps, you will see that on Chrome and Firefox, two menu appears and on Edge only the custom one (which is the expected behavior and this also works fine on Mac).

```
var ContextMenu = document.getElementById("my-context-menu");

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function (ev) {
    ShowContextMenuGoolge(ContextMenu, ev);

            /** this stop NOT stopping DOM 'context-menu' event from firing */
            ev.stop();

});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {

    HideContextMenuGoolge(ContextMenu);
});
}
```

Expected behavior (Screenshot from Chrome in Mac):

[image]

What actually is happening (Screenshot from Chrome in Windows):

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting issue so thanks for posting it. I cannot reproduce the "bug" you assume to be browser related. I only see one context menu in all browsers (MS OS), which is fired correctly by the event handler. Can you post some screenshots to show the expected behaviour and the current output you get? May I also ask you to specify how you load the Google Maps API, through an HTML script or do you use an HTTP client via NPM? Show me the script that initialiase the Maps API as well, if you can (recommended)

Comment: @rags2riches I have added the screenshots. I initialize Maps API via npm.

Comment: @anandsons.byethost32.com Is the solution below working out well for you or you want me to expand on any other thing that may not be clear?

Comment: Dear Himanshu, on the 20th of December you posted the above issue and within the same day, I have given you one of the possible solutions. Do you still have some issues with the below solution or can we close this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution on both FireFox and Google Chrome so just add this piece of code at the very top of your js file:

```
window.onload = (function(){
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt){
        console.log(evt)
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(evt){
      console.log(evt);
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
  });
})();
```

Also remove the `ev.stop() method` as it won't do anything. See below.

> JavaScript within the browser is event driven, meaning that JavaScript
>   responds to interactions by generating events, and expects a program
>   to listen to interesting events. User events (such as "click" mouse events) are **propagated from the DOM to the Maps JavaScript API.** These events are separate and distinct from standard DOM events.

[See this link for the above reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview)

Also note that disabling the `right-click event` via `contextmenu` in the browser may not be the ideal solution. I suggest additional resarch on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent half a day trying to solve this exact same problem, and the solution posted here and in several other threads on this issue just wouldn't work for me. Here's what did:

```js
// Add a listener to the Intelligence Bounds to serve a context menu
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon, 'rightclick', (evt) => {
  if (evt.vertex && myPolygon.getPath().getLength() > 4) { // Don't let them delete a node if it would turn us into a line

// Set timeout is used only because it solves the issue of Windows Chrome/Firefox browser context menu overlaying our own
setTimeout(this.onVertexRightclick, 0, evt.vertex, this)
  }
});
```

I honestly don't understand why this works but I'm glad someone posted it. Wrapping the handling of the event in a setTimeout() set to zero ms was the only fix that worked.

All the other fixes I've seen relate to the 3.0 maps API and were posted ~ 2018. I'm using the newer Angular widget that came out in 2019 and is supposed to simplify usage and just wrap the API to my understanding, so perhaps that's the difference in this case.